# Is $\mathbb T^\infty$ homeomorphic to an open subset in $\ell^2$?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

More specifically, letting $\mathbb S$ be the set $\{\kern.5mm\exp({\rm i}\,t):0\le t<2\pi\kern.6mm\}$ with the induced topology from the complex plane, let $\mathbb T^{\kern.6mm\infty}$ be the product topological space of denumerably many of copies of $\mathbb S$. E.g. from page 15 in [this paper](http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1970.2/Main/icm1970.2.0013.0018.ocr.pdf) we know that all separable infinite-dimensional Fréchet spaces are homeomorphic. So the question is whether $\mathbb T^{\kern.6mm\infty}$ is homeomorphic to an open subset in some separable infinite-dimensional Fréchet space.

**Edit.** After reading Igor Belegradek's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/143188/is-mathbb-t-infty-homeomorphic-to-an-open-subset-in-ell2#comment369309_143188), I now realize what I should have realized already before posting the question. Namely, the motivation behind the question was whether $\mathbb T^{\kern.6mm\infty}$ could be made a manifold modelled on Fréchet spaces with charts defined on open subsets. These sets are $\sigma$−compact, and hence cannot be homeomorphic to open subsets in any infinite-dimensional Baire topological vector space. So there is no hope to turn $\mathbb T^{\kern.6mm\infty}$ into a manifold modelled on Fréchet spaces. The question can be closed.

Comment: Your notation is rather nonstandard: $S^\infty$ usually denotes an infinite-dimensional sphere, rather then an infinite product of circles.

Comment: Would perhaps $\mathbb T^{\kern.5mm\infty}$ be better?

Comment: Sure, either that or $(S^1)^\infty$ would be great.

Comment: The space $T^\infty$ is compact (by Tychonov), so if it is homeomorphic to an subset of a metric space, that subset is also closed. Thus $T^\infty$ cannot be homeomorphic to an open subset of a Frechet space.

Comment: So after this negative answer the question could be modified by taking the uniform product distance on $\mathbb{T}^\infty$  (that is the distance induced by the inclusion in $\ell_\infty(\mathbb{C})$).

Comment: You could also ask whether $\mathbb{T}^\infty$ is _locally_ homeomorphic to an open subset of Frechet space.

Comment: Yet another argument: $\mathbb{T}^\infty$ is not locally homeomorphic to an open subset of any topological vector space because it is not locally contractible (no open set is simply connected).

Comment: $T^{\infty}$ is also locally compact, but any infinite dimensional topological vector space is not locally compact. Therefore $T^{\infty}$ is not locally homeomorphic to any topological vector space.